# Get background color of text from webpage

Tags: java, css, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

My web application has primary and secondary search.

Based on the search term the web application highlights the first search term in blue color and the second search term (or search within as they call) is highlighted in purple color. This is mostly done using java script in the back end for which we do not have access.

I need to automate this scenario, since the color of the element is not seen in page source i am unable to identify the background color of the element using selenium.

Please suggest me a suitable solution to get the background color of the searched terms

Comment: what do you mean by automate? are you looking for styling or how to change it in Javascript directly?

Comment: Currently i am using selenium to do my automation testing. I am able to enter primary and secondary search terms. I just want to see if the background colors are highlighted properly using automation

Comment: I need to check if the background of color even is highlighted properly for primary and secondary search.

Comment: can you post html of the search button before search, first search term and second search term.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood so far from your question is, you wanted to style anchor visiting search links.
Links can be styled with any CSS property (e.g. color, font-family, background, etc.). In addition, links can be styled differently depending on what state they are in.

The four links states are:

```
a:link - a normal, unvisited link
a:visited - a link the user has visited
a:hover - a link when the user mouses over it
a:active - a link the moment it is clicked
```

You can change any background color of the link by styling anchor tag directly in your css external or inline file. This can also be handled very easily from Javascript or Jquery styling attributes. Go for the below example and play with it to see if this is how you needed your links to behave.

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link*/
a:visited {color:#000000;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

Remember the order to process the same

***Source***:http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

See if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove default link style by using style="text-decoration : none;" for 'a' tag

`<a href="#" style="text-decoration : none;">
 This link is not underlined.</a>`

Comment: Thanks Udara, your solution will work when the background color is preloaded and static. In my scenario the background color of text is being dynamically changed, based on search term and i need to check for this scenario